# Pontryagin Dual of $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$

Tags: duality-theorems, profinite-groups

Let $\mathbb{F_p}$ be the field with $p$-elements and $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$ denotes the power series ring of one variable.

Question: Can we say what will be the Pontryagin dual Hom$_{\text{cont}}$ $(\mathbb{F_p}[[T]], \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$? where $\mathbb{Q}_p$ denotes the  the field of p-adic numbers and $\mathbb{Z}_p$-is the p-adic integers.

All I can say that Hom$_{\text{cont}}$ $(\mathbb{F_p}[[T]], \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)=$ Hom$_{\text{cont}} (\mathbb{F_p}[[T]], \mathbb{F}_p)$ is a co-free $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$-module. Since $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$ is a PID, co-free(injective modules) and divisible modules are the same. As a result  Hom$_{\text{cont}}$ $(\mathbb{F_p}[[T]], \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)$ becomes a $\mathbb{F_p}[[T]]$-divisible module, but I want to know the complete description of Hom$_{\text{cont}}$$(\mathbb{F_p}[[T]], \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: You can consider $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ because $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ is of exponent $p$. Have you considered the pairing $(A,B) \in \mathbb{F}_p((t))^2 \longmapsto \mathrm{Res}_{t=0}(A(t)B(t))$?

Comment: @Aphelli Sorry, I have no idea what I can get from the pairing mentioned by you.

Comment: If $\pi$ is the pairing, $A \in \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \longmapsto \pi(A,\cdot)$ generates at least some elements of the dual. I think the map is onto and that the kernel is exactly $\mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$, which gives you a explicit Pontryagin dual. But Qiaochu Yuan’s approach is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pontryagin dual sends limits to colimits so we get the filtered colimit of $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{F}_p[T]/T^n, \mathbb{F}_p)$. As a vector space this is $\mathbb{F}_p[S]$, and I believe the $\mathbb{F}_p[[T]]$-module structure is given by $T(S^i) = S^{i-1}$.